# How to determine cutoff using Youden Index?

Tags: logistic, python, roc

I am trying to determine the MCID of a PROM using a anchor based method (ROC). I have the following dataset.

| Delta_PROM | Status Anchor |
| --- | --- |
| 30,6 | 1 |
| 18,7 | 0 |

The dataset has 800 rows. I'm using python, and I did the following:

1. Train/test split the data
2. Fit a Logistic model
3. Predicted probability of 1
4. Plotted ROC using y_test and predictions

My AUC is 0.8, which is a good value for this type of methodology and context. I calculated the Youden Index which is 0.87. Now I'm stuck: How do I know the Delta_PROM threshold using this value?